# Git Bash file which runs command in current directory, then opens chrome

Tags: bash, node-modules, git-bash

Per the title, I'd like to have a .sh file which I can drop into a directory and then:

- Run http-server (the simple node server) in the current directory
- Open Chrome and point it to that server

The idea is that when I'm developing I can quickly run this bash file and see the current version of whatever html/css/javascript website I am working on. My issue is that if you run a command in a bash file, it isn't run in the current working directory, but rather in the root directory (as far as I can tell). So if I just write `http-server` in my file, it will run a server not in the current directory, but in `./`.

To fix this, I want to cd to the directory first, and then run the script. `current_dir=$(pwd)` will give me something close to the current directory, but I can't put that directly into a cd command because it (1) doesn't have quotes around it, so spaces in directory names will make it not work, and (2) it starts with `/C/` instead of `/C:/`. Can anyone advise me on how to fix this?

My current code looks as follows.

```
curr_dir=$(pwd)
cd $curr_dir
http-server
start chrome localhost/XXX
```

And, as mentioned, results in the http-server command being run in the wrong place:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://192.168.56.1:8081
  http://192.168.1.21:8081
  http://127.0.0.1:8081
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

e: For anyone who happens on this later, this isn't actually a problem -- see the accepted answer. I had another typo.

Comment: The `/C/` vs `/C:/` thing is a Cygwin-specific thing. It probably works both ways (otherwise `pwd` would be pretty useless.)  My advice, as always, is to think hard about whether you really want to be on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; the commands you run always run in the current directory.  Otherwise, if your hypothesis were correct, e.g. `ls` would always show the files in the root directory.

If you want to run a command which is in a different directory, you want

```
../relative/path/to/command
```

or

```
/absolute/path/to/command
```

Neither of these change the current directory of the shell.  The current working directory of the process you create will remain the directory you were in when you run this command. (Even if you run it in the background and subsequently change to a different directory in your interactive shell, for example.)

If you want the command to run in the directory where the script lives on the disk, something like this can occasionally be useful.

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

but again, most of the time, you want and need your commands to run in the current directory.

(There *are* situations where you want a script to process data files in a fixed location, but these are rare exceptions.  Until you have such a situation, consider it a bug to use `cd` in a shell script.)

If you have a command `http-server` somewhere on your `PATH`, just `http-server` will run that.  You should normally *not* have the current directory on the `PATH`, but to run the binary in the current directory instead of from anywhere on the `PATH`, you say so:

```
./http-server
```

Comment: Huh, maybe there is some other error then? It doesn’t appear that when http-server runs it is actually running in the directory, as no server is hosted, even tho as mentioned ls and cd work fine. My impression was that http-server was unique in this respect. If I open a git bash terminal in the directory and manually type http-server, however, it does show up. Based on what you’re saying, it sounds like I’m wrong though. I’ll doublecheck that I’m not getting some other error. You’re probably correct that I should just start dual booting Linux either way tho :/

Comment: Update: you're totally right, I had a different typo in my actual script. Thank you for going above + beyond w/ the explanation!